# Reference Request on Sullivan's paper

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

I am reading Sullivan's 1985 Non-wandering paper(for the paper, see [https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math627.S13/Sullivan-1985-Nonwandering.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ebishop/classes/math627.S13/Sullivan-1985-Nonwandering.pdf)). Section 3 in the paper says that a maximal collection of disjoint simple closed geodesics decomposes a hyperbolic Riemann surface into components conformally equivalent to 'funnels' or '(degenerated) pair of pants'. It referred to Thurston's notes 'Geometry and topology of 3-manifolds', but I failed to find the proof. (I am very sorry to ask for help since the proof surely exists somewhere). Or are there any other recommendations for this proposition?

And here is another somewhat vague question. Can we represent Kleinian groups into some holonomy group of some 'Lorentian' manifolds? I am just wondering about the relationship between Kleinian groups and physics, although I know almost nothing about physics (except a little special relativity).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I am not sure what the real question is: Are you asking for an existence of a maximal collection of pairwise disjoint simple closed geodesics? Or: Are you asking about conformal geometry of complementary regions (in which case you should explain the terminology '(degenerated) pair of pants'.) Your last question about Lorentzian geometry is even less clear. There is an obvious Lorentzian structure on a 4-manifold with Kleinian holonomy, why don't you use  it?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I apologize for the ambiguity. For the first question, a pair of pants means a hyperbolic surface conformally equivalent to a disk removing two small disks and endowed with a metric where the boundary components are geodesics. Degenerated means the removed disk can become a point. I was asking where I can find a proof about one can always decompose a hyperbolic surface into components like these using geodesics. For more details, I have attached the link to the paper.
For the second, I mean which Kleinian groups can be represented as a holonomy group, and is it interesting?

Comment: Your definition of a **degenerate** pair of pants is almost, but not quite, right. You should define it as a Riemann surface conformal to the 2-sphere minus three disjoint closed round disks of possibly zero radius. Otherwise, there is an obvious counter-example, the triply-punctured sphere. Incidentally, since you are a beginner, I suggest reading a proof of Sullivan's theorem in "Complex dynamics" by Carleson and Gamelin. Even for a professional mathematician, reading Sullivan is frequently a challenge.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, my definition is not precise. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reference I know for the decomposition of a Riemann surface, compact or not, is the book of Hubbard, [matrix editions](https://www.matrixeditions.com/), *Teichmüller Theory and Applications to Geometry, Topology, and Dynamics, Volume 1: Teichmüller Theory.*

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want.